# Tree Hash: How to verify if a range is tree-hash-aligned?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, amazon-glacier

"Tree Hash" is a concept similar to Merkle Tree/Tiger Hash Tree used by Amazon Glacier to verify the data integrity of a subsets of a given datastream.

In order to receive tree hashes from Amazon Glacier when retrieving data, the specified byte range has to be "tree hash aligned".

[The concept of "tree hash aligned" is described here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations-range.html)

Quoting from the developer documentation:

> A range [A, B] is tree-hash aligned with respect to an archive if and only if when a new tree hash is built over [A, B], the root of the tree hash of that range is equivalent to a node in the tree hash of the whole archive. [...]
>
> Consider [P, Q) as the range query for an archive of N megabytes (MB) and P and Q are multiples of one MB. Note that the actual inclusive range is [P MB, Q MB – 1 byte], but for simplicity, we show it as [P, Q). With these considerations, then
>
> - If P is an odd number, there is only one possible tree-hash aligned range—that is [P, P + 1 MB).
> - If P is an even number and k is the maximum number, where P can be written as 2k * X, then there are at most k tree-hash aligned ranges that start with P. X is an integer greater than 0. The tree-hash aligned ranges fall in the following categories:
>
>   - For each i, where (0 <= i <= k) and where P + 2i < N, then [P, Q + 2i) is a tree-hash aligned range.
>   - P = 0 is the special case where A = 2[lgN]*0

Now the question: How do I verify programmatically if a given range [startByte, endByte] is tree-hash-aligned? Programming language does not matter.

Test cases:

```
[0,0) => true
[0,1) => true
[0,2) => false
[0,3) => true
[1,2) => false
[4,5) => true
```

Comment: Megabyte alignment *is* required.  *"P and Q are multiples of one MB"* (thus P is an integer offset from the start of the file, in MiB).  It isn't possible to be tree-hash-aligned and not megabyte-aligned; the set of all possible tree-hash-aligned blocks is a subset of all possible megabyte-aligned blocks, with an apparent  exception that allows a block to be megabyte-aligned with an endpoint past the actual end of the file and still be tree-hash-aligned.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're right. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a *basic* implementation of the *is_treehash_aligned* function in  **Python**:

```py
import math

def max_k(x):
    return 1 + max_k(x/2) if x % 2 == 0 else 0

def is_treehash_aligned(P, Q):

    if (Q < P):
        return False
    elif (P % 2 == 1):
        return Q == P
    else:
        ilen = Q - P + 1    # size(interval)
        if  not (((ilen & (ilen - 1)) == 0) and ilen != 0):
            return False    # size(interval) ~ not power of two
        if P == 0:
            return True
        else:
            k = max_k(P)
            i = int(math.log(ilen, 2))
            return i <= k

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    ranges = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), \
              (4, 5), (6, 7), (2, 4), (6, 8), (5, 6), \
              (4, 4), (1, 1), (4194304, 5242879), \
              (4194304, 5242880), (4194304, 5242881)]

    for r in ranges:
        ret = is_treehash_aligned(*r)
        print("[" + str(r[0]) + ", " + str(r[1]) + ") => " + str(ret))
```

The output is:

```py
[0, 0) => True
[0, 1) => True
[0, 2) => False
[0, 3) => True
[1, 2) => False
[4, 5) => True
[6, 7) => True
[2, 4) => False
[6, 8) => False
[5, 6) => False
[4, 4) => True
[1, 1) => True
[4194304, 5242879) => True
[4194304, 5242880) => False
[4194304, 5242881) => False
```

Note that:

- I adopted **your notation** for intervals rather than the one provided by the *instructions*. As a consequence, it is possible to assume that each interval is *Megabyte aligned*.
- The result for the test-case `[4194304, 5242880)` differs from what you put in your original question, though I double-checked it and I am somewhat confident it is correct.
- if `N` is known, which is not the case in your test-cases, then when `P == 0` one should also accept any range s.t. `Q >= floor(N)`, and not only those with a size that is *a power of two*. A similar argument could be made for *sub-trees* for which there is nothing else on the *right*. Both of these cases would match the *definition* of *Tree-Hash Alignment* given [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations-range.html), but not the *instructions* for identifying it.

---

**Notes**: both the question and the [description](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations-range.html) of the problem appear to be albeit confusing.

1. The test cases are given with the notation `[A, B)` where `A` is the index of the starting block and `B` is the index of the ending block *(included)*, assuming that the whole archive is comprised by an array *--indexed starting from 0--* of *N* blocks size *1 MB* each (except possibly the last one). E.g.:

   ```
   [0,0) => true
   [0,1) => true
   [0,2) => false
   [0,3) => true
   [1,2) => false
   [4,5) => true
   ```

   However, the *instructions* assume that the ranges are given with the notation `[P MB, Q MB – 1 byte]`.
2. The *instructions* are **misleading**.

   For example, here it says:

   > If P is an even number and k is the maximum number, where P can be written as 2k * X, then there are at most k tree-hash aligned ranges that start with P

   The *power* symbol appears to be omitted, perhaps due to wrong *HTML* code, as the sentence should be *"the largest `k` s.t. `P = (2^k)*X`"*.

   Another example is:

   > For each i, where (0 <= i <= k) and where P + 2i < N, then [P, Q + 2i) is a tree-hash aligned range.

   Assume for example that `Q = P + 1`, `i > 0` and `k > 0`. Then the interval `[P, Q + 2^i)` has size `= Q + 2^i - P = P + 1 + 2^i - P = 2^i + 1 > 1`. However, by construction there exists no such *tree-hash* aligned range with an odd size larger than one. The proposition should be: *"[...], then `[P, P + 2^i)` is a tree-hash aligned range"*.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing test cases. [4,5) is basically equivalent to [(1024*1024*4, (1024*1024*5)-1]. But I think you pretty much nailed it.